# How to display data on a ListView that I receive using RxJava

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2

"In the tags of this question pointed out Java, since Java and Kotlin are compatible, and here's an example that is very similar to Java"

I have created a program that displays data in a ListView. I am learning RxJava2, and decided to make an example where the data obtained using RxJava is displayed in a ListView. Below is the code for the ListView adapter.

```
class AdapterListView(ctx: Context, intent: Intent): RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
    private var context: Context? = null
    private var widgetId = 0
    var data: ArrayList<String>? = null

    init {
        context = ctx
        widgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        data = ArrayList()
    }

    override fun onDataSetChanged() {
        data!!.clear()
        Observable // There is pseudo observable for example
        .observeOn(SchedulerProvider.ui())
        .subscribe (
                {
                    for(i in it.indices) {
                        Log.e("IT::", it[i])
                        data!!.add(it[i])
                    }
                },
                {
                    data!!.add("ERROR")
                }
            )
            .toString()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {}

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return data!!.size
    }

    override fun getViewAt(position: Int): RemoteViews {
        val rView = RemoteViews(context!!.packageName, R.layout.list_view)
        rView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, data!![position])

        return rView
    }

    override fun getLoadingView(): RemoteViews? {
        return null
    }

    override fun getViewTypeCount(): Int {
        return 1
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

With subscribe, I get the data and add to a dynamic array. With Log.e, the data is displayed on the screen, i.e. there are no errors, but they are not added to data, or they are added, but since RxJava runs asynchronously, so no data is added to data. Wanted to know if there is a way to implement it so that you can output data to ListView using RxJava?

Comment: You need to call adapter notifyDataSetChanged method once items loaded

Comment: @GurgenArustamyan 
But in my example, the adapter class inherits from RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory, and not from BaseAdapter, since I am displaying ListView in Widget, and therefore the notifyDataSetChanged method will not be called for me, or I do not know how to call correctly in this case.

Comment: It seems to me that you are not calling notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged. If the data has changed you need to notify the widget that the collection view needs to be updated.